# How do I setup a nested/chained function within a C# Class

Tags: c#

Here is what I'm trying to setup

My class is named Inventory
I have a static function named List_Departments()

I would like to be able to add an additional function to modify the previous

For Example:   Inventory.List_Departments().ToHTML() would return an HTML formatted string containing the data from List_Departments()

If possible i'd like to reuse the same code for another function such as List_Categories()

I would really appreciate a nudge in the right direction on this. I just can't seem to find the correct terminology/ search term to pull up the info I need. Thank you very much for your help, and sorry for the somewhat stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're referring to is [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the `List_Departments` method return an object that has a `ToHtml` method.

Depending on what your exactly methods are returning, you might make a class called something like ObjectList, which would have a `ToHtml` method, and have the `ListDepartments` and `ListCategories` return instances of it.

Alternatively, and especially if your methods are returning existing classes such a `DataTable`, you could make an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) for that class called `ToHtml`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your functions List_Departments() and List_Categories are returning some *typed* object correct?  That being, the object returned would have to have a Method created in it's class definition called ToHTML().  If the two functions return the same type of object then, you only need to define it once.  If they return two different types, then you will have to define the ToHTML() method on both return types class definitions.

Unless I'm missing something here, these two functions don't require the static modifier.

If the returning types are types that you don't have source code access to, then you can define an extention method for each type that will process the type of object being returned and can display the ToHTML() for it.

Comment: Some of the setup functions in the app are going to need listings of all departments/ categories. There will be Inventory objects later but for convience sake I'd like to be able to access the list without declaring anything.

Comment: ... and yeah you are absolutely right. I don't want to go crazy with these but it seems like a better approach for this situation than ten different function names to restate the same retrieved data. Thanks so much for the help and the fast response- you guys rock.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't supply much info, but using [Extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) seems a good approach to me.
An example turning an string into an int:

```
public static class StringMethods {
    public static int ToInt(this String subject) {
        int result;
        int.TryParse(subject, result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Assuming `List_Departments` returns `Department`:

```
public static class DepartmentMethods {
    public static string ToHtml(this Department subject) {
        // Whatever you want to do.
    }
}
```

If you do have acces to the internals of the type returned by `List_Departments`, you can also just add ToHtml there.

Answer (score 1):

the search term you're looking for is Method Chaining :-)
http://www.bing.com/search?q=method+chaining

This is something along the lines of what jQuery does.  Basically, you make an object that has all of the methods that you want to be able to chain.  Then, using the builder pattern, you can chain all the calls together until you call some final "result" method (ToHtml in your case).

```
public class Inventory
{
    private IEnumerable<Departments> departments;
    private IEnumerable<Items> items;

    public Inventory ListDepartments()
    {
      // load up departments to a class level field
      return this;
    }

    public Inventory ListItems()
    {
      // load up items to a class level field
      return this;
    }

    public string ToHtml()
    {
      // convert whichever enumerable was previously loaded to HTML
      return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

That lets you do things such as:

```
inventory.ListDepartments().ToHtml();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ToHTML()` function is a function that acts on the type returned from `List_Departments()`

For example:

if `Inventory.GetProduct(0)` returns an int. You can use `Inventory.GetProduct(0).ToString()` because ToString() is a method of an integer type.

In order to do this, `List_Departments()` would have to return a custom object that has a method called ToHTML() say

```
public class Department() { 

   public HtmlDocument ToHTML() {
      //Create the html document to return here
   }
}
```